# URL compare to regular expression

Tags: bash

```
regexp='^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=\w+)(?!\S+http:\/\/)(?:\S*)$'

fURL()
{
       echo -n "Enter the YouTube URL to download: "
       read URL
       if [ "$URL" != "$regexp" ]; then
               echo "${red}Invalid YouTube URL!${normal}"
               fURL;
       fi
}
```

I test my script with http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tfTWHbtv_-Y - but it still says it's invalid.

I tried modifying the code:

```
echo $URL | grep "^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=[^?]*v=\w+)(?:[^\s?]+)?$"

if [ $? -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "${red}Invalid YouTube URL!${normal}"
    fURL;
else
    echo URL is good.
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use =~ operation to compare against regexp.

Answer (score 0):

It's your regular expression that's the problem - you need to escape the `/`:

```
^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=\w+)(\S*)$
```

This will validate your test url correctly

*expression is an example not tested with every possible URL*